Command for concatenation of paths
Consider the following code which draws, in this order, the segment joining (1,4) to (1,2) (path A), a certain hyperbola joining (1,2) to (2,1) (path B), and the segment joining (2,1) to (3,1) (path C):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[
name path = A ,
] coordinates{ ( 1 , 4 ) ( 1 , 2 ) } ;

\addplot[
name path = B ,
domain = 1 : 2 ,
]{ 2*x / ( 3*x - 2 ) } ;

\addplot[
name path = C ,
] coordinates{ ( 2 , 1 ) ( 3 , 1 ) } ;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I would like to create a single path, which I would name "fusion", by concatenating these paths into a single one.
Is there a way to accomplish this? Something like
\merge[name path = fusion , paths = { A , B , C } ]


You need spath3 to manipulate soft paths like that.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[/tikz/spath/save global=pathA] coordinates{(1,4) (1,2)};
\addplot[/tikz/spath/save global=pathB, domain=1:2]{2*x/(3*x-2)};
\addplot[/tikz/spath/save global=pathC] coordinates{(2,1) (3,1)};

\draw[red] [spath/use={pathA}] [spath/use={pathB, weld}] [spath/use={pathC, weld}];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit:
The combined path can be named like this:
\path[name path=fusion] [spath/use={pathA}] [spath/use={pathB, weld}] [spath/use={pathC, weld}];

Fill between plot and x-axis:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[fill=pink, draw=none, forget plot, domain=1:2]{2*x/(3*x-2)} \closedcycle;
\addplot[fill=pink, draw=none, forget plot] coordinates{(2,1) (3,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot[] coordinates{(1,4) (1,2)};
\addplot[domain=1:2]{2*x/(3*x-2)};
\addplot[] coordinates{(2,1) (3,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, your solution only "draw" the concatenation of the paths, but the concatenation itself is not saved as a single path (besides, the previous \addplot commands already draw the pieces, so that the last command indeed overwrites these).

What do you mean by "only "draw""? What do you want to do with the path?

I need the concatenation to be named as a single path in order to apply the fill between operation (with the horizontal axis).
